# Which is the best way to call multiple method repeatedly in c# timer or thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

**Thread:**

```
for (; ; )
{
    Thread newThread = new Thread(MainWindow.LumEnergyInformation);
    newThread.Start();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

**Timer:**

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(LumEnergyInformation);
myTimer.Interval = 10000; // in milliseconds
/myTimer.Start();
```

Comment: Surely it depends a lot on what your method does? if it takes a long time and you just need it over and over, or its quick and you want it ever x seconds or?? what?

Comment: In x(60) seconds and how to implement multiple methods in timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases, Thread or Timer, your methods will just be executed in different threads, in parallel with other threads.

The main difference is this:

- Thread will use a dedicated thread for the task
- Timer will use a thread taken from Thread Pool and the thread will be used for the task only when the method runs. Between one interval and the next one the same thread could be used by someone else.

Therefore all comes down to your use case: if your application uses a lot of threads Timer can be more efficient. If the method you are invoking takes a lot of time, there would be no benefits to use Timer instead of Thread as the thread would not be recycled.

Answer (score 0):

The question should be - What to choose Timer or Thread if the using method is threadsafe. As of this is the most important to consider. So does you method need anything outside of it's own focus? Does it need to use a lot data (in the meaning of many objects) or just one?

Secound important question is, can the main content run, without a result of the method?

If you can answer both questions with a yes then go straig forward with threads. If not, tryx to evaluate the effort needed to answer both questions with yes and head to threads.

Reason for threads vs timer

Timer is primarly just an huge event construct. The Timer.Tick is event driven, the Timer.End is event driven and so on. All is controlled via the based OS. Also if the timer want's to execute it's DoSomething your main application has to halt and execute the code.

So if your code is 100% standalone or threadsafe ==> Go with threads.